# How to monitor a process's resource usage(time, memory) at run-time?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I am trying to monitor a process's resource usage(time, memory, system calls) at run-time, is there apis in windows like ptrace, setrlimit in linux ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you monitor resource usage at compile time? :P What you're looking for are tools called profilers. Search for C++/ C# profilers on the web.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I am trying to write a simple online judge on windows, it can compile user's code and run the program in limited time and memory, like https://www.spoj.pl .So I need some suggestions about what winapis should I use.

Comment: Explain more what you need.  It sounds like you want to place a restriction on how much memory and how much CPU time a process is allowed to use.  Is that so?  Please define what you mean by memory because there are many different metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of APIs depending on what you want in C/C++ (or C# through P/Invoke):

e.g, to start looking,

Process CPU time (UM/KM):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223(VS.85).aspx

Process VM (working set):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683226(v=VS.85).aspx

Process I/O data:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683218(v=VS.85).aspx

You can try these to start.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods. First of all, you will want to run the process as a low-integrity process. This is similar to how Internet Explorer runs; such processes are isolated from other processes, the registry and the file system (except for selected low-integrity directories).

Secondly, you are in control of the executables. You should whitelist which DLLs and functions they are allowed to use. There are just too many variants of `CreateProcess` to blacklist. This might even require rebuilding the CRT to eliminate dangerous functions.

Sandboxing C# code is somewhat easier. You obviously have to restrict it to safe code. [PEVerify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) can help there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system tools like ProcMon, Process Explorer, ProcessMonitor and Performance monitor for such kind of analysis. Tracing system calls are actually a tough job, there will be hundreds of systems calls will be made by an application. I think you must use some tools like Inter VTune Analyzer for such type of deep profiling.